# automate installation of your softwares

Tags: windows-7, backup, formatting, automation

I'll be re-install my Operating system in my desktop, It would be a clean version of windows7. I wonder if there's a software that lets me install my application automatically or an easier way to install all my old application. I still have all my installer sitting in my hard drive. I just need a software to automate it, but not to hard to configure it. What would be the process that you would recommend if you're in my shoes. I'm still using my old windows 7 here in my desktop. But before I format my old drives, I would want to get your suggestions and opinions.

I also stumbled on a cool software "Windows Post-Install Wizard" But the problem of this is I'm having hard time to configure it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this other question answer your question, or do you need something else than that? [One-stop-shop installer for free Windows software?](http://superuser.com/questions/69751/)

Comment: Three cheers for Ninite!

Comment: yeah similar, but i'm looking for more specific apps. Those that you suggested are using mostly portable and freewares. I'm looking on a software that let me customize what to install. I need to install apps that are in my drives (eg, Microsoft Office, Adobe CS4, etc)
But thanks, it has some cool apps.

Comment: @variant agree! Ninite is cool!

Answer (score 1):

The answer I've found is via some basic batch scripting.  Most installation software packages come with some type of silent install setup.

Here are a couple of great resources for automating things:
http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php
http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/ (specifically on the left menu under intermediate users>applications)

I've got a nifty cd that installs all sorts of things all automated.  I install windows 7 (also automated), then pop the disk in, and viola, brandy new system.

Answer (score 0):

[Install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) is a purely GUI program. The 4j just means it runs on java and therefore is multiplatform. It supports silent installs too (ie: 1 click and forget) just don't put any interactive prompts (actions) in your install4j project. It doesn't require knowledge of Java, but it has portions in it for conditional expressions which use the Java language.

Your usecase doesn't need Java/conditional expressions, and you can just put a collection of actions which install various .exe's and bundle all your third party .exe's into the install4j project or invoke any interactive GUI/prompt executables. Install4j will then export a single packed .exe which will execute all your *actions*, in this case just run each third party installer 1 by 1. Hopefully your third party installers all have silent options, because even batch scripting won't make it automated if the installers you have are interactive.