# Automate application installs

Tags: windows, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automate installation of application](https://superuser.com/questions/170676/how-to-automate-installation-of-application)

I'm in IT support and find myself installing the same 5 or 6 applications multiple times on different windows computers through out the day.

Is there a program that could install all my apps for me with out me doing it manually? Ideally i'd like a script (or installer) that I could execute from a flash drive.

The applications are; office 2010, adobe reader, flash, java, a pdf printer.

I need to be able to do this all offline because not all the PCs have intrnet access.

Your ideas please.

Answer (score 3):

[Ninite Pro](https://ninite.com/pro).  I have used the free personal edition and it is incredibly helpful.  It can't install Office 2010 (Only a trial version of Office 2007), but it can install Adobe Reader, Flash, Java, and CutePDF (Which is what I assume you're using).  It also has an offline installer command line option.  The only downside to this is that it's $20 a month, but you might be able to get reimbursed for that.

---

EDIT: To install Office 2010 you might want to take a look at [this](https://ninite.com/help/enterprise/custom.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this just using switches in each of the installers.

For Office 2010 you should have a look at these:

[Configure a silent installation of Office 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630736.aspx)
[Setup command-line options for Office 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178956.aspx)

The following post states how to install Adobe Reader silently:

[Adobe Reader X Silent Install](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3287048#3287048)

While you can install Flash silently using the "-install" switch.

In regards to Java I'm not sure if you're meaning JRE or SDK but silent install options are available for the offline installation files.

As you don't state what PDF printer you'll be using can't really give you any help with that but if it happens to be CutePDF the following will help you with that:

[How to silently install CutePDF Writer and GPL Ghostscript](http://theether.net/kb/100096)

If you test these and they all work successfully you could write a small batch script to automate this further.

Answer (score 0):

Its a fair bit of work upfront and probably far from the ideal solution to this particular problem, but I've used [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) before to automate various repetitive actions in gui apps. Thought it worth a note.