# An application for Windows 7 which can get a list of software and auto install it

Tags: windows-7, automation, updates

I've checked something like ninite or filehippo auto checker but it doesn't seem suite my need. I want an application that:

- It can save installed app in my windows and save to a list or something like that.
- We can config it's installer based on url or our installer in windows, so we can install all of our applications easily every time I reinstall my windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [automate installation of your softwares](http://superuser.com/questions/168810/automate-installation-of-your-softwares)

Comment: also http://superuser.com/questions/170676/how-to-automate-installation-of-application